# Can a professor ask you to get a medical clearance from your doctor

Tags: professorship

My professor asked me to get a medical clearance from my dictor stating that I am free from my medical ailment. Can a professor do that?

Comment: Gonna need a lot more details.... I can certainly imagine instances where safety would require a professor to ask about medical issues (e.g., traveling to remote areas)...if this in a classroom setting, then I'm surprised any professor would want to go into the legal minefield of medical issues, but whether they "can" do that is another matter, depends on the specifics....

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the institution has a responsibility to all students and faculty in terms of infectious things and it is probably in the detail of the enrolment form you signed somewhere...

I have seen situations where students were told to **not** come to class and stay in their rooms until the Doctor cleared them - this was when europe had a "flu / respiratory " bug a while back...

Students are also sometimes required to provide proof of sickness, or death of a relative, when asking for repeat exams or assessments. Had one case where the student photocopied a medical certificate and changed the dates - got caught because the signature was identical on 5 certificates - size, position on the paper etc etc